# WhatsApp Intent

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, tasker, intents

I'm trying to automatically change the text status (not the photo/video status) in WhatsApp via Tasker by sending an Intent. My problem is that I don't know if it's possible to call the status to change it, and if it is possible, how to do that.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If such a way exist, it would pose a "huge" privacy risk since a rogue app can easily wreak havoc in somebody's life.

Answer (score 2):

There is no intent to change text status directly but you can use a workaround by using Autoinput which is a tasker plugin.

Here is the profile description.
[You can download XML for easy import here.](https://pastebin.com/dfUc2Rqc)

First, you need to set a variable for text for your WhatsApp status.

```
A1: Variable Set [ Name:%content To:intent test Recurse Variables:Off Do Maths:Off Append:Off ]
```

Next, Launc WhatsApp

```
A2: Launch App [ App:WhatsApp Data: Exclude From Recent Apps:Off Always Start New Copy:Off ]
```

Click the menu of whatsapp

```
A3: AutoInput Action [ Configuration:Type: Text
Value: More options
Action : Click Timeout (Seconds):20 ]
```

Wait for 1 second

```
A4: Wait [ MS:0 Seconds:1 Minutes:0 Hours:0 Days:0 ]
```

Click status in Menu

```
A5: AutoInput Action [ Configuration:Type: Text
Value: status
Action : Click Timeout (Seconds):20 ]
```

Again, wait for a second

```
A6: Wait [ MS:0 Seconds:1 Minutes:0 Hours:0 Days:0 ]
```

Click edit to edit status

```
A7: AutoInput Action [ Configuration:Type: Text
Value: edit
Action : Click Timeout (Seconds):20 ]
```

Wait for a second

```
A8: Wait [ MS:0 Seconds:1 Minutes:0 Hours:0 Days:0 ]
```

Paste the whatsapp status from variable named content.

```
A9: AutoInput Action [ Configuration:Type: Focus
Text to Write : %content
Action : Write Timeout (Seconds):20 ]
```

wait for 1 second

```
A10: Wait [ MS:0 Seconds:1 Minutes:0 Hours:0 Days:0 ]
```

Finally, click ok to update the status.

```
 A11: AutoInput Action [ Configuration:Type: Text
Value: OK
Action : Click Timeout (Seconds):20 ]
```